# Hive - cannot recognize input 'insert' in select clause

Tags: hive, hiveql

Say I've already created table3, and try to insert data into it using the following code

```
WITH table1
AS
(SELECT 1 AS key, 'One' AS value),
table2
AS
(SELECT 1 AS key, 'I' AS value)
INSERT TABLE table3
SELECT t1.key, t1.value, t2.value
  FROM table1 t1 
  JOIN table2 t2
  ON (t1.key = t2.key)
```

However, I got an error as ***cannot recognize input 'insert' in select clause.*** If I simply delete the insert sentence, then the query runs just fine.

Is this a syntax problem? Or I cannot use with clause to insert?

Answer (score 0):

Use INTO or OVERWRITE depending on what you need:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table3  --this will append data, keeping the existing data intact
```

or

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table3 --will overwrite any existing data
```

Read manual: [Inserting data into Hive Tables from queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)

Comment: @QingyunBao check maybe there some TAB characters. Replace them with spaces